# What does batch normalization do if the batch size is one?

Tags: tensorflow, batch-normalization

I'am currently reading the paper from Ioffe and Szegedy about Batch Normalization and im wondering what happens if the Batch size is set to one. The computation of the mini-Batch mean(which is basically the value of theactivation itself) and variance(should be Zero plus constant epsilon) would lead to a normalized Dimension of Zero.

Yet this small example in tensorflow Shows that something different is Happening:

```
test_img = np.array([[[[50],[100]],
                   [[150],[200]]]], np.float32)
gt_img = np.array([[[[60],[130]],
                [[180],[225]]]], np.float32)
test_img_op = tf.convert_to_tensor(test_img, tf.float32)
norm_op = tf.layers.batch_normalization(test_img_op)

loss_op = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels = gt_img,
                                                             logits = norm_op))

update_ops = tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)
with tf.control_dependencies(update_ops):
    optimizer_obj = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(0.01).minimize(loss_op)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.group(tf.global_variables_initializer(), 
                      tf.local_variables_initializer()))
    print(test_img)
    while True:
        new_img, op, lossy, trainable = sess.run([norm_op, optimizer_obj, loss_op, tf.trainable_variables()])
        print(trainable)
        print(new_img)
```

So what is TensorFlow doing differently(moving average?!)?

Thank you!

Comment: It does [Instance-Normalization](https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.08022)

Comment: Could you please elaborate a little bit more about that paper? And from where did you get that knowledge, that it is doing something like instance normalization?

Answer (score 0):

Because of beta, the learnable parameter for translation which is enabled by default, the normalized output will not necessarily be zero.

Moving averages for input mean and variance will be computed during training and can be used at testing (if you set `is_training` accordingly).